# Formatting census queries using python wrapper for US Census API

Tags: python, census

I am using Sunlight Lab's Python wrapper class for the U.S. Census API. However, I am having some difficulties formatting my queries, as the examples the provided were not super robust. The core files from this library are a bit difficult to interpret, so I was hoping someone could help me format a query.

How can I format a query to look up the population of a given zipcode using this wrapper class?

Here is what I have so far:

```
from census import Census
from us import states

c = Census("66897530f6275c25f574d3d469c1f4c730b9174a")

print c.sf1.get(('NAME', 'P0080001'), {'for': 'zipcode:*'})
```

but this gives me an error.

P0080001 corresponds to total population according to http://api.census.gov/data/2010/sf1/variables.html

Relevant code in the wrapper code:

https://github.com/sunlightlabs/census/blob/master/census/core.py

Comment: What error do you get?

Comment: census.core.CensusException: error: unknown/unsupported geography heirarchy

Comment: I think I am formatting the zip code incorrectly...?

Answer (score 1):

I got this to work by calling `c.sf1.state_zipcode`. The `sf1` includes the `state_zipcode` geography, so you have to pass both the state and zipcode to return results.

Using your example:

```
from census import Census
from us import states

c = Census("66897530f6275c25f574d3d469c1f4c730b9174a")

c.sf1.state_zipcode(('NAME', 'P0080001'),states.CA.fips,'94104')
```

This returns

```
[{'NAME': 'ZCTA5 94104',
  'P0080001': '406',
  'state': '06',
  'zip code tabulation area': '94104'}]
```

You can also replace the zipcode '94104' with '*' to get data from all zip codes in California.